# Запрос данных с помощью curl

Tags: php

Почему то не работает код, почему - не понимаю. Код получает ответ от curl и ищет (должен искать) в этом ответе слово yes, если найдено - то выводит текст, если нет - то другой. Сам код:

```
<?PHP 
// CURL
$ch = curl_init('http://dev.local/phpwhois-4.2.2/example.php?query=domain.ru&output=object');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
curl_setopt  ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$curl = curl_exec($ch); // выполняем запрос curl
echo $curl;
curl_close($ch);
// whois ответ
if(preg_match('~\s*yes\s*~u', $curl))
  echo 'Домен занят';
else
  echo 'Доступно для регистрации';
?>
```

Ошибка странная, точнее её там совсем нет, но - если curl отдает текст с yes, то не работает, пишет то что в else, а если не отдает такой текст - тоже else. Если просто весь текст который отдает curl самому занести в переменную то работает.

Вот что отдает скрипт в curl`e (на этот ответ пишет то что в else):

> regrinfo->Array  disclaimer->Array 
> 0->By submitting a query to RIPN's
> Whois Service   1->you agree to abide
> by the following terms of use:
> 2->http://www.ripn.net/about/servpol.html#3.2
> (in Russian)
> 3->http://www.ripn.net/about/en/servpol.html#3.2
> (in English).  domain->Array
> name->hashcode.ru   nserver->Array 
> ns1.nameself.com->81.176.95.18 
> ns2.nameself.com->88.212.207.45
> status->REGISTERED, DELEGATED,
> VERIFIED   created->2010-11-05
> expires->2014-11-05   source->TCI 
> **registered->yes** regyinfo->Array 
> referrer->http://www.ripn.net 
> registrar->RUCENTER-REG-RIPN 
> servers->Array   0->Array 
> server->ru.whois-servers.net 
> args->hashcode.ru    port->43 
> type->domain rawdata->Array  0->% By
> submitting a query to RIPN's Whois
> Service  1->% you agree to abide by
> the following terms of use:  2->%
> http://www.ripn.net/about/servpol.html#3.2
> (in Russian)   3->%
> http://www.ripn.net/about/en/servpol.html#3.2
> (in English).  4->  5->domain:     
> HASHCODE.RU  6->nserver:    
> ns1.nameself.com.  7->nserver:    
> ns2.nameself.com.  8->state:      
> REGISTERED, DELEGATED, VERIFIED 
> 9->person:        Private Person 
> 10->registrar:     REGTIME-REG-RIPN 
> 11->admin-contact:
> http://whois.webnames.ru  12->created:
> 2010.11.05  13->paid-till:     2014.11.05  14->free-date:     2014.12.06  15->source:        TCI  16->  17->Last updated on 2014.07.27
> 12:31:31 MSK  18->

Comment: При использовании file_get_contents так же, однако если тестить код с file_get_contents на http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php , то почему то работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено, оказывается тот файл который отдавал текст требовал user-agent